# Python hasattr() function on a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a message as shown below.

```
<LayerReg. SVersion= 1, RegCount= 1, LayerReg= [ <TRegRec. JLID= 1, ACM= 0, JLIState= eAdminState.OK, Flags= 0, FullList= 0, JLIDCount= 0, PUIDs= [  ]> ]>
```

I want to search for attribute `JLID`

If I use `hasattr(msg,'JLID')` it is returning false. How can I check for the attribute `JLID` in the above message.?

msg is of type

```
class LayerReg(model.Struct):
    SVersion  = UInt8_Field()
    RegCount  = UInt8_Field()
    LayerReg  = NestedStructArray(TRegRec, RegCount)
```

Comment: is that a string? is it a `message` object? what is it?

Comment: If that message is a string, you need to read the documentation for `hasattr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message is already parsed and in the object you mentioned, then I'm guessing you can access that field via:

```
msg.LayerReg[0].JLID
```

And if you want to check for that attribute, then it's:

```
hasattr(msg.LayerReg[0], 'JLID')
```

But that's just guessing based on the code we can see here.